# Random X Y coordinates

Tags: c#

I want do get some random (x, y) coordinates, but I dont know how to do it.  The coordinates must have a relative difference of 60 between each other.

For example, in pixels:

```
x    y
0    60
0    120
0    180
60   0
120  60
180  60
....
```

How can this be done using C#?

Comment: If they "must" have anything then they aren't random, or even pseudo-random.

Comment: @Andrei: It is perfectly acceptable to speak of a random selection from some set with known properties (e.g. floating point numbers in the interval [0,1], odd integers in the range [1, 99], or in OP's case, pairs of integers in [COORD_MIN, COORD_MAX] with both elements divisible by 30.) A uniform probability distribution may or may not be implied, depending on context.

Comment: Please explain your requirements in more detail; what does "relative difference" mean? Your examples only have four different values that all differ by multiples of 60 units. It is also helpful to know what you are trying to accomplish. Are you going to do something with these coordinates after?

Comment: Am having same problem as previous commentor: in what way do the above examples have a "relative difference of 30" between one another?

Comment: sorry, type wrong, was 60. i will use this coordenates to draw a graphic that contains squares, and i dont want to overlap the squares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
x = random(0, n)
if(x - 30 < 0)
    y = random(x + 30, n)
else if(x + 30 > n) 
    y = random(0, x - 30)
else 
    // in this case, x splits the range 0..n into 2 subranges.
    // get a random number and skip the "gap" if necessary
    y = random(0, n - 60);
    if(y > x - 30) {
        y += 60;
```

Make sense?  It basically boils down to "pick 2 random numbers between 0 and n differing by more than 30."  The above doesn't handle the case where n < 60.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want those coordinates be in range 0 - n. Then you have to get a random number between 0 and n / 30 and multiply it by 30. So:

```
Random r = new Random();
coordinate_whatever = r.Next(n / 30) * 30;
```